# fdisk can't find USB storage

Tags: linux, usb, storage, fdisk

A problem with USB storage in Linux has cost me more than one day: `dmesg` says USB is detected, but `fdisk -l` can't find USB storage.

My kernel is 2.4.32.

Infomation about this USB storage can also be found via `proc`:

```
# cat /proc/scsi/usb-storage-0/0 
   Host scsi0: usb-storage
       Vendor: USB 2.0
      Product: USB Flash Drive
Serial Number: 00000000001485
     Protocol: Transparent SCSI
    Transport: Bulk
         GUID: 048d11670000000000001485
     Attached: Yes
```

`lsmod` shows:

```
# lsmod | grep usb
usb-storage            27800   0 
usbcore                56864   0  [ehci-hcd uhci usb-storage]
scsi_mod              108120   1  [usb-storage]
```

scsi

```
 # cat /proc/scsi/scsi     
    Attached devices: 
    Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
      Vendor: USB 2.0  Model: USB Flash Drive  Rev: 0.00
      Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI SCSI revision: 02
```

"fdisk -l /dev/sda" gives me nothing, and "strace fdisk -l /dev/sda" shows me:

```
open("/dev/sda", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)  = -1 ENXIO (No such device or address)
```

tail of dmesg

```
hub.c: new USB device 00:1d.7-2, assigned address 2
usb.c: kmalloc IF af910660, numif 1
usb.c: new device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb.c: USB device number 2 default language ID 0x409
Manufacturer: USB 2.0
Product: USB Flash Drive
SerialNumber: 00000000001485
scsi0 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
  Vendor: USB 2.0   Model: USB Flash Drive   Rev: 0.00
  Type:   Direct-Access                      ANSI SCSI revision: 02
WARNING: USB Mass Storage data integrity not assured
USB Mass Storage device found at 2
usb.c: usb-storage driver claimed interface af910660
usb.c: kusbd: /sbin/hotplug add 2
hub.c: port 3, portstatus 100, change 0, 12 Mb/s
hub.c: port 4, portstatus 100, change 0, 12 Mb/s
hub.c: port 5, portstatus 100, change 0, 12 Mb/s
hub.c: port 6, portstatus 100, change 0, 12 Mb/s
hub.c: port 7, portstatus 100, change 0, 12 Mb/s
hub.c: port 8, portstatus 100, change 0, 12 Mb/s
```

Comment: Seriously?  2.4?  That's over a decade old.  Time to upgrade.  10 years ago.

Comment: yeah, but it's property of company, not my own box. any solution to figure out what's up without upgrading? thx

Comment: Are they also still using Windows 95?  Beat whoever is in charge with a rubber hose until they stop using obsolete software.

Comment: you are very humorous, lol.

Comment: Isn't redhat still using the 2.4.32 kernel as default for their enterprise security systems? This might not be outdated, just lts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I solved this problem! :-P

It turned out to be that I `insmod scsi_mod.o` and `sd_mod.o`, but the kernel had support for SCSI already.

sigh~

I  also found that scsi_mod should be `insmod`'ed before sd_mod, and ehci_hcd.o before usb-storage.o. If not, dmesg will say `usb.c: USB device not accepting new address=2 (error=-71)`.

Answer (score 0):

"kernel is 2.4.32" - really? Can't you use something a bit more modern?

Have you tried looking at "cat /proc/scsi/scsi"? How about "fdisk -l /dev/sda"?

"fdisk -l" on its own doesn't always try all disk-like devices in the system. Giving it a specific device will force it to look at that and tell you its partition table.

Comment: thanks for ur reply.i've update my question with scsi and "fdisk -l /dev/sda". somewhere need to look into to find more infomation? upgrading is not allowed cause it's property of company.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is somewhere in hotplug - the SCSI device is there, but nothing in /dev. Unless it's somewhere else in /dev. Do "ls -lR /dev > file" before and after plugging it in and diff the results. Do you have to use this specific system? Is it Intel or some other architecture?

Comment: there's no difference before and after plugging it in:-(. i must use this system and it's Intel architecture. anywhere need to check on ? i really don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look more closely at dmesg when you insert the usbstick - my guess is that t isn't getting plumbed at /dev/sda.

Comment: i've post tail part of dmesg, something wrong?

Comment: Does anything funny show up in /dev?  Is that everything from dmesg from the time you plug it in?

Comment: /dev is exactly the same before and after plugging usb stick in, dmesg's output is a bit long (185 lines), what i posted is just the end part of it. do i need to post it all so you can analyse it better?