# usb memory won't mount (not manually either) and is not in fdisk. Why?

Tags: usb, mount, mp3-player

Please forgive yet another "I can't mount a USB drive", but the output doesn't match what previous threads seem to assume.

**the device:** USB mp3-player of the simplest type. Just a USB stick with headphone jack.

**what happened:** Mac crashed whilst it was mounted. Now Mac will see it but won't read or format it, windows won't even see it, and Linux will chirrup when it is plugged in or removed but it doesn't mount.

**what I think the problem is:** That it doesn't show up in fdisk or on GParted, but why, what this means, and what to do about it I don't know. (I'm really only a basic user parroting commands without fully knowing what's going on)

I found [another thread](https://superuser.com/questions/390632/fdisk-cant-find-usb-storage), saying he solved it with `insmod`, but I don't understand how. Help please? insmod mounts kernel modules, but how do I know which one and why did it work before and not now?

Thanks for any suggestions and/or explanations about what's going on! (and I don't care if all the data is erased, it would just be nice to have it working again)

-r

**Extra details**, because from various other forum threads I've understood that the following can be of interest.

With the usb plugged in `ls -l /dev/* | wc -l` give 500, unplugged the I get 492.

In Disks it is noted as being

"Model" USB 2.0 Boot Loader (0001)

"Serial Number" USB_2.0_Boot_Loader-0:0

"Device" /dev/sdb

the rest are just -, and the "Edit Mount Options" has the automount has ON. With the usb plugged in, i can conrfirm this with

```
r@Sammy ~ $ ls /dev/ | grep sd
sda
sda1
sda2
sda3
sda4
sda5
sda6
sda7
sdb
```

because unplugged I get

```
r@Sammy ~ $ ls /dev/ | grep sd
sda
sda1
sda2
sda3
sda4
sda5
sda6
sda7
```

however, lsblk doesn't find it

```
r@Sammy ~ $ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    20G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0  83.3G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  46.7G  0 part /
├─sda6   8:6    0   2.8G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda7   8:7    0  80.1G  0 part /home
```

Similarly, fdisk doesn't see it

```
r@Sammy ~ $ sudo fdisk -l 

Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc9af158c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    41945087    20971520   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *    41945088    42149887      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        42149888   216739839    87294976    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       216741886   488396799   135827457    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       216741888   314566106    48912109+  83  Linux
/dev/sda6       314566656   320430079     2931712   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       320432128   488396799    83982336   83  Linux
```

Using the same plug-unplug method lsusb gives tells me that it is called AliCorp, this is the printout with it plugged in

```
r@Sammy ~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0ac8:c33f Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. Webcam
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0402:7103 ALi Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

The verbose output for the device is

r@Sammy ~ $ lsusb -v

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0402:7103 ALi Corp. 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0402 ALi Corp.
  idProduct          0x7103 
  bcdDevice            0.01
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                1 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

and `dmesg` is TLDR to the point that it overflows the history of the terminal and I can't even scroll back to the start.

Obviously, I also tried mounting it manually

```
r@Sammy ~ $ sudo mount /dev/sdb /home/r/Desktop
mount: no medium found on /dev/sdb
```

Answer (score 0):

> the device: USB mp3-player of the simplest type. Just a USB stick with
>   headphone jack.
>
> what happened: Mac crashed whilst it was mounted.

For "of the simplest type", may we read "it cost next to nothing"? :)

You're assuming the problem was caused by the Mac crashing while it was mounted. But probably cause and effect are the other way round: if a computer's writing to a USB device which gets removed prematurely, problems can occur on the device, but in this case it's a media player so your Mac was only reading data from the device.

It sounds to me as though your USB stick suffered a hardware failure, crashing the Mac. And it won't work now because, well, it's suffered a hardware failure. Time to get another perhaps.

Comment: I'm glad £15 is nothing to you. You're a lucky person, and I wish you long and continued success in life.